# php dropdown selected value

Tags: php, dropdown

I'm having an edit form and within a dropdown box with movie-titles.
One of them should be selected though, so say DVD_id: 100.
How do I make this work in the code below?

```
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Site name" class="col-md-4 control-label">DVD Title</label>
        <?php
        $query = "Select DISTINCT dvd.dvdname, dvd.dvd_id, FROM DVD where ORDER BY dvd.dvdname";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Couldn�t execute query.");?>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <select id="box" name="dvdtitlefield" class="selectpicker form-control" multiple title="Choose one of the following..." >
                <?php
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                    extract($row);
                    echo '<option value="'. $dvd_id .'">'. $dvdname .'</option>';
                }?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Side note: You have an encoding issue. `Couldn�t` and could also affect the query.

Comment: you want to have an option pre selected?

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: `echo '<option value="'. $dvd_id .'" <?= $dvd_id == $selected_id ? 'selected="selected"' : ''?>>'. $dvdname .'</option>';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the selected attribute of the option tag to make any option by default selected

```
<select>
<option value="tiger">tiger</option>
<option value="lion">lion</option>
<option value="zebra">zebra</option>
<option value="cat" selected>cat</option>
</select>
```

In your code you can just check which option you want to be selected by default and apply an if condition for it

example

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Site name" class="col-md-4 control-label">DVD Title</label>
    <?php
    $query = "Select DISTINCT dvd.dvdname, dvd.dvd_id, FROM DVD where ORDER BY dvd.dvdname";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Couldn�t execute query.");?>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <select id="box" name="dvdtitlefield" class="selectpicker form-control" multiple title="Choose one of the following..." >
            <?php
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                extract($row);
                if($dvd_id==100)
                {
                echo '<option value="'. $dvd_id .'" selected>'. $dvdname .'</option>';
                }
                else
                {
                echo '<option value="'. $dvd_id .'">'. $dvdname .'</option>';
                }
            }?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```